# chrome xml download warning

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

precondition : disable below options from crome settings 
safe browsing & Ask where to save each file before downloading

if I try to generate xml file from my rest service i get waning message "

> This type of file may harm your computer. Do you want to keep
>   .xml anyway ?

"

surprisingly warning comes only with xml if i change file type (i.e. var fileName) to any other like .txt or .pdf even .foo it doesnot give waning.

Is there any way to disable this warning programmatically rather than manual change in chrome settings.

javascript code

```
var aFileParts = ['<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'];
var blob = new Blob(aFileParts, {type : 'text/html'}); 
var fileName = 'text.xml';
var urlCreator = window.webkitURL;
var url = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
var link = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
link.setAttribute("href", url);
link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
link.click();
urlCreator.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

Comment: Ask yourself this: what good would the warning be, if a website could just disable it?

Comment: surprisingly warning comes only with xml if i change file type (i.e. var fileName) to any other like .txt or .pdf even .foo it doesnot give waning.

Answer (score 1):

This feature cannot be turned off sadly.

However, you can somewhat get around it by having chrome manually ask you where each file should be stored before it is downloaded.